# GA E-Commerce Transactions out by ~50%

Tags: google-analytics, transaction

Have done a bit of researching and searched various boards and topics and haven't been able to shed much light onto this. It seems like it's been a common problem over the various versions of Magento and I understand that it will never be 100% accurate but for the sake of conversion rate tracking it would be great to improve the current amount of transactions being tracked.

- Magento ver. 1.7.0.2
- Google API enabled with tracking code implemented
- GA code confirmed to be present on checkout page source

Issue:

- Only ~50% of transactions are showing in E-Commerce tracking in GA.

I can't see any theme or trend among the missing transactions, I did read it one thread that it may be guests who have signed up during the purchasing process but I'm not sure how to check this.

It's a huge amount of transactions missing. Does anybody have any idea of a solution or things I can look for or point a developer in the direction of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A very common cause is that people close the page as soon as they see their transaction went ok. The GA code doesn't have a chance to load and send data.

This is aggravated if there's other resources on the page that prevent DOM loaded JS from firing.

It seems a bit on the high side though, but if you have New Relic for both Application and Browser you should be able to correlate the throughput of the application part and the browser part for `/checkout/onepage/succes`.

New Relic loads a script on top and bottom to measure load time. If the browser part does not come through, then the client closed the browser.

If the deviation between application throughput and Browser is no where near what you're missing, strike this of the list of possibilities. If it's a sizeable chunk of the traffic then look closer at the browser timings that do get recorded to look for problematic areas in loading or rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at your order data and look for some kind of trend? In my case there was a mistrack in orders with paypal and sofortüberweisung and I figured out that a lot of costumers actually close the paypal success page for example before being redirected to the success page on my site.

No success page = no tracking of that order. I haven't found a solution for that problem though..

Answer (score 0):

It could be down to the following reasons -:

1. Customers never reached to the order confirmation page
2. Customers closed the browser immediately after placing order
3. Cookie is disabled in customer browser

You can use Google Measurement Protocol APIs to send offline transactions on order creation event or alternatively you can use the following plugin which comes up with the option to send transactions on order creation and also comes with the option to compare Magento and Google Analytic Transactions and send missing transactions to GA.

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for missing transactions in Google Analytics. The most common reasons that I have come across are:-

- Disabled cookies on the browser
- Disabled javascript on the browser
- Customers clicking away after placing the order
- Some payment gateways do not redirect customers to the order success page
- Conflicting with other extensions

The best solution that I have found is to resend missing transactions to Google Analytics using the Measurement protocol API.